Random Voronoi mesh with geometry nodes
I would like to start with a number of randomly scattered points all lying in one plane. These points define a Voronoi mesh in this plane.

Is it possible to construct such a mesh dynamically from the given points within geometry nodes?

Do you want it to be 2D or 3D ? I don't think I can help you but it should be doable.

I got the same problem - I don't think I can help you, but there must be ways to calculate this (which I don't know), and if you can calculate it, there is probably a way to set it up with Math nodes...
